# Access to Files Outside the Home Directory Chroot - For every Users

Tags: mount, permissions, chroot

I want to allow access to /var/www/dev/ to every user in my system (+50) via their home directory (so they can access via FTP with chroot_local_user=YES)

For one particular user I can do:

```
mkdir /home/user_name/www_dev
mount --bind /var/www/dev/ /home/user_name/www_dev
```

And then make this configuration permanent by editing /etc/fstab:

```
/var/www/dev  /home/user_name/www_dev    none    bind    0       0
```

My question is: the above is for 1 particular user, how can I make this work for every user in the system? and automatically when I create a new user?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this? Thank you